# incompatible signature with supertype - abstractmethods vs Liskov for enforcing naming

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I have an ABC class that I am deriving from to make some children.
Each of the children have the same general structure, and the same methods, but those methods need to take different arguments (different variants of the same type of model). I also want to type check those arguments, and ensure naming to avoid any dumb implementation errors.

For example, I have several scorecard models to implement. All have the same basic structure (take some arguments, do some stuff, return an integer score). Each child's `score` method takes a different set of inputs specific to that individual model.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class BaseScorecard(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def score(self):
        """
        abstractmethod to enforce consistent naming to enforce consistent naming
        for sanity and automatic doc-building
        """
        return NotImplementedError
    
    def do_common_thing(self)
        """Some complicated common logic that having a parent class helps with"""
        ...


class Scorecard1(BaseScorecard):
    """A specific scorecard"""
    def score(
        self,
        var1: int,
        var2: int,
        var3: str,
    ) -> int:
        """
        score method for this scorecard. Takes some arguments 
        specific to this one and does some complicated logic.
        """
        ...

class Scorecard2(BaseScorecard):
    """A different scorecard for a different population"""
    def score(
        self,
        var1: str,
        var2: float,
    ) -> int:
        """
        A different model that takes only 2 arguments, and of different types.
        """
        ...
```

I obviously want to have the same method naming so that a) the naming stays consistent across the project (different programmers don't use subtly different names), and b) because there is automatic generation built from the modules, if I register `Scorecard1` then the script expects to find a `score` method to document.

Of course this actually runs fine but mypy will give an error like `test.py:12: error: Signature of "score" incompatible with supertype "BaseScorecard"`.

Now, **I understand that this violates Liskov**. In theory, you should be able to call the supertype method with the arguments for the subtype, but the child arguments violate that in this case.

In this case, I really don't care, the parent method should never be called on its own, including via `super()`, all I really want is to enforce consistent method naming, but also be able to type the arguments in the child method.

I seen some similar things in other questions or mypy issues, but the answer is always just "that violates Liskov, don't do that, do something else", which is true but not actually very helpful. I've never actually found any suggestions for what to try instead.

Is there a better pattern I should be using to enforce what I want?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What advantage do you get from having `BaseScorecard` define a `score` method itself when its subclasses define the same method with different signatures?

Comment: Would `def score(self, *args, **kwargs)` (in the defintion of the base class) change anything? (I'm not sure what _incompatible_ means exactly.)

Comment: @quamrana I don't really need the base class to have the method, I am defining it there as an `@abstractmethod` to make sure that the child class has it, and with the exact naming, since that's what I actually care about.

Comment: @Timus that's then similar to this thread https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4250. If I set the base abstractmethod to take *args, **kwargs, then mypy expects the child to also take arbitrary args/kwargs, in order to satisfy the liskov substitution principle. I get it, but its a bit of a pain in the butt...

Comment: @Jack Thanks! (Wasn't a suggestion to do it that way - seems not in line with your intent - just curiosity what mypy makes of it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `BaseScorecard` generic over the arguments it receives. Because variadic generics aren't supported, you can wrap the arguments in a `@dataclass`.

Side notes:

1. You want to make the base `score` annotated as returning `int` instead of not putting anything there (defaults to `Any`).
2. You want to `raise` `NotImplementedError` instead of `return` it.

```
T = TypeVar("T")

class BaseScorecard(ABC, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def score(self, args: T) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

@dataclass
class Scorecard1Args:
    var1: int
    var2: int
    var3: str

class Scorecard1(BaseScorecard[Scorecard1Args]):
    def score(self, args: Scorecard1Args) -> int:
        ...

class Scorecard2(BaseScorecard[None]):
    def score(self, _: None) -> int:
        ...
```

`Scorecard1` then effectively takes a `var1`, `var2` and `var3`, and would be called like this:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = "abc"

args = Scorecard1Args(var1, var2, var3)
Scorecard1().score(args)
```

`Scorecard2` effectively no args (maybe it outputs a constant score), but to make it compliant with the `BaseScoreboard` interface, we make it take a `None`, and it would be called like so:

```
Scorecard2().score(None)
```

If all you want to do is enforce consistent naming, then this may be overkill. But benefit of using `Generic` is now you can consider two subclasses of `BaseScorecard[X]` equivalent if `X` is the same, whereas if you use `*args, **kwargs` in the base signature, you lose that type safety.

Comment: That's super interesting, thanks! Splitting off args like that could also solve another problem I have. I'm going to do some more experiments and see what is and isn't worth it, but marking it accepted anyway since it is at least a novel solution (to me)

Comment: All that painful dance just to follow some f..ng principle... No thanks, type: ignore.